The Desktop, Downloads and Documents folders have disappeared from the Sidebar
Desktop and Dowloads folders are AWOL in Finder.

I've checked the settings for Finder:

Sequoia 15.0.1

This question is similar to: Favorites disappears from sidebar in Finder. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Let's link these @MartinR but if we were to close these, this would stay open IMO since it's clear and the other question has some "questionable answers" that aren't relevant for current macOS

The common cause of this is the disclosure caret to show Favorites is toggled to the hidden state, which hides all content in that section of the Finder sidebar.
This is hard to see when you are close to it with the pointer and invisible by default now.

Move your mouse to the right horizontally from the word favorites in the sidebar towards the separator to the file listing. Click to expand the category and show your favorites in the sidebar.
There can be some obscure corruptions that further break the sidebar (especially if you use tool to modify the preferences directly and not via GUI) - test if that's your case by making a new user on the Mac and observe if the system is broken or just your user preferences.
